# How is it possible to continue solutions for a differential equation along t?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation $y' = e^{\sin y+t} + t\cos(y)$. I rewrote it as 
$$
y(t) = y(0) + \int_{0}^{t}ye^{\sin y+t}+t\cos y
$$
I'm asked to prove that every solution can be continued for every t.

I know that I should probably use Gronwall's lemma somwhere here but I'm not sure where. Also, more generally, how can I know if a differential equation's solutions can be continued? Thanks.

Comment: Either there is a missing $y$ in the equation or an extra $y$ in the integral.